# Access localhost on fedora linux

Tags: linux, fedora

I have installed Apache and supporting tools use the instruction of article
[install-apache-web-server-fedora](https://fedoramagazine.org/install-apache-web-server-fedora/).

When I access test page using `http://localhost`, I am getting page not found, what this mean the server not installed correctly?

Comment: does `http` service appear if you run `firewall-cmd --list-all`?
also that guide doesn't mention anything about setting up the service: `systemctl status httpd` should be Loaded and Active

Comment: I had run the given command in the terminal and I am getting the following details [hanuman@localhost ~]$ firewall-cmd --list-all
FedoraWorkstation (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens32
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http https mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:

Comment: @user3373819 `systemctl status httpd` ?

Comment: ● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor prese
   Active: inactive (dead)
lines 1-3/3 (END)

Comment: well.. Active: inactive (dead) ....  does it start? `systemctl start httpd`

Comment: wow great man working now. i am very new to linux platform some more this is for temporary time and very short time for my task. thank you very much

Comment: you could also `systemctl enable httpd` to have it start automatically

Answer (score 2):

Run in terminal:

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

and then:

```
systemctl enable httpd.service
```